# How can I make a bar chart where I can sub-divide each of the three x-axis categories?

Tags: r, bar-chart

I'm attempting to make a bar graph, using three different columns from my data set to make up the x-axis (Number_DS, Number_US, Number_A), (and 'Number attracted' as the y-axis) with each of these three variables representing data for each of three different fish species, so basically, three categories on the axis, each subdivided into three sub-categories.

The graph below (which I made by summarising data I had on a previous occasion and producing a concise matrix) shows the kind of graph I'm attempting to produce (without the error bars).

In addition, I'm also planning on calculating standard error or deviation to produce error bars for each. However, I'm struggling to find a way to do so with my data in the format that it is in (different to previous occasion). Does anyone have any code that may help sort the data in a way that generating this graph is possible? I've added some of my data below in hopes that it helps this question make more sense!

Thank in advance

[image]

```
Species         NumberDS    NumberUS    NumberAcross   Number attracted
Atlantic cod    0            0           92             0
Atlantic cod    0            2           0              0
Haddock         9            0           0              9
Whiting         0            0           4              4
Haddock         0            0           1              0
Whiting         0            1           2              3
```

Comment: So you got the image above, but it's not right? If not, then what's wrong about it. (I haven't been able to connect the data to the graphic.)

Comment: I usually do this manually by specifying the `at` argument. But you should provide example data and your attempt to use the `barplot` function; this might help narrow your question down to where you're really having trouble

Comment: BondedDust and rbatt, I cheated  a little by summarising the data and producing a matrix from that to produce the graph  above, but I can't calculate standard error/deviation to add error bars to the graph by doing that. The main problem I'm having is arranging the above data, which is in a different format from the format I used to make the graph on a previous occassion, in a way that I can reproduce the graph shown (if that makes sense!!)

Comment: You need to post data in a format that can be pasted into a running R session. Use `dput`. Cannot give advice on creating sd bars if your data is summarized.

Comment: BondedDust, apologies for not explaining myself properly. I summarised the data the first time I was looking at this data months ago, which I used to create the graph above. I'm now back to looking at a similar data set to previous (a few lines of which are shown above - not summarised), which I want to use to recreate a graph similar to that shown above along with sd or se error bars, but I'm finding it difficult to even make the graph with the format my data is in. I hope this makes more sense

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I got your problem. Assuming df is your data.frame.

```
sps=split(df,df$Species) #Species is the first column
totals=sapply(sps,function(sp)apply(sp[,-1],2,sum))

bp=barplot(as.matrix(t(totals)),legend.text = TRUE,args.legend=
          list(x = "topright",bty="n",cex=.8,ncol=1),
        beside=T,col=1:ncol(totals),xaxt="n")
axis(1,at=bp[2,],labels=row.names(totals),las=2,cex.axis=.5,tick = F)
```

Is that what you want?

[image]

Comment: Robert, along the right lines thank you! Though I need 'Number_attracted' as the y-axis